# React - don't parse certain HTML tags in dangerouslySetInnerHTML

Tags: reactjs

So I'm building a chat system in React. Ideally, things like `<strong>` or `<em>` or `<h2>` would be parsed correctly, and formatted at such. However, I'd like things like `<link>` or `<script>` to just be displayed as text (for formatting and security reasons, of course).

Is there a way to pick which HTML tags I'd like to parse, and which to ignore?

Comment: It's possible to process the string with regular expressions, for example, but I'd advise against it. Hackers will always find a way to outsmart your script tag stripping code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a battle-tested library like [DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify) to strip out all tags/attributes you don't want to allow. As Patrick says, do not attempt to roll your own using regex.